# How to take content from a textbox and place it in both a variable and div in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, textbox

I want to have five variables, all empty and waiting for content to be put into them. I also want the content of a textbox to be placed into one of the five variables above and posted into a specific div that already exists. I want the script to check if the other variables have content before picking which variable to place the new content. I will give you a small example to understand what I am looking for.

Example:

Say I have three people on my website, they enter content into a textbox. Press the button. I want the content from the textbox to be place in the first available variable, and also into a specific div named "promoted". So say John, Jim, Jake are all on my website, John types "google.com" and presses submit. I want "google.com" to be put into the first variable and into the div making it display on the website. Then Jim types "stackoverflow.com" in the textbox and presses submit, I want "stackoverflow.com" to be put into the second variable and into the div making it display on the website, below "google.com". Jake types "yahoo.com" into the textbox and presses submit. I want the third variable to be "yahoo.com" and it placed into the div, displaying it on the website below "google.com" and "stackoverflow.com". Once all five variables are full, I want the next content being submitted to replace the first one. I hope this makes sense.

Code I've tried:

```
function promote() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input').each(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith('<div class="promoted"><a href="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).val() + '</a></div>');
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet, post some code of what are you tried so far or make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I got you right here.. You can't do that with only Javascript, you will need some kind of serverside script too. Static vars, saved in text file, DB or something like that on the server. If those people would sit on different computers at your site with only javascript they will only see thier own javascript vars.